# Problems with jquery functions adding. File doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a noob in js and jquery. So I've a problem. I need to insert a new line in table after clicking the button. Here is my code:

```js
 $(function() {
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("tr:last").after(<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>)
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Добавть преподавателя</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>  
        </table>
```

Comment: Wrap the HTML inside the function with quotation marks (`"`) and import jQuery with the full URL

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the HTML when calling `after`. Also note that this will result if you add more buttons to the page you end up with all buttons adding rows to your table (better use an _id selector_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed to wrap your html `""` in the `after` method because you need to 
 wrap it as string this methods takes `String`

You can check jQuery [doc](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
$(function() {
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $("tr").after("<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>")
                });
            });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button>Добавть преподавателя</button>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>text</td>
                    <td>text</td>
                    <td>text</td>
                    <td>text</td>
                </tr>  
            </table>
```